# Cannot see everything in the opened window

Tags: 16.04

This happens every time I open any application even the Terminal , and I can't move it or drag it. Ubuntu 16.04

[image: first Image]

[image: My Terminal Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move a window without seeing its title bar:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and start dragging with the primary mouse button (mostly the left one) at any part of the window.